# Creating a new Android Application Project

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new to Android Development. I tried to create a new Android Application Project using Eclipse but when I click 'Finish' the windows remains open. When I close it, the folder hierarchy is as follows:

[image: Hierarchy]

I don't think that this is correct since no AndroidManifest is present

Also, these are the errors that I get in the error log:

[image: Errors]

Comment: What do you mean by "the window remains open"? Do you mean the project wizard? Did you install the platforms correctly?

Comment: Yes, the project wizard. I followed a tutorial on how to install the platform.

Comment: suggest you to reinstall the ADT plugin.

Comment: I tried to install it and I got the same problem

Comment: You have either incorrectly entered some data or missed something out.  If you look closely, the wizard will tell you whats wrong.

Comment: But when I create a sample project, the folder hierarchy is correct

Comment: I have solved my same problem by changing eclips.

Comment: I tried both Helios and Juno. Same problem :/

Comment: Open error log (Window > Show View > Error Log) and check if you have errors.

Comment: @Patrick I added a screenshot of the error log

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes deleting your Debug Certificate would work. This would be located inside your profile folder (In Windows, **%USERPROFILE%/.android** would be the correct location). Now clean build your android project. It should work.